# Unable to delete exact array item

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of URL's, from which I am attempting to delete a URL that matches my specification.

```
array = ["http://www.redmine.ca/", "http://red.redmine.ca", "https://black.redmine.ca/Pages/welcome.aspx", "http://webmail.redmine.ca", "https://blue.color.redmine.ca/groups"]
```

My attempt to delete `"https://blue.color.redmine.ca/groups"` from the array is:

```
array.delete("https://blue.color.redmine.ca/groups")
# => ["#i-", "www", "", "iPwx", "wbi", "", "wwwbk", "", "wwwf", "wwwii-w"]
```

The `delete` seems to target characters individually rather than matching the entire string. I have also attempted to use `delete_if` and `reject!` which seem to yield no results or break the code.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. What you mentioned is `String#delete`'s behaviour. `Array#delete` does not work like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is simpler. Try:

```
array -= ["https://blue.color.redmine.ca/groups"]
```

Good luck ;)

Comment: This code is more inefficient as you create a new array to place the string just to use the `-=` operator, whereas the `delete` does the job without adding any extra overhead.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti: Not only that but it also creates another one: the result.

Answer (score 1):

The code works for me:

```
2.1.5 :001 > array = ["http://www.redmine.ca/", "http://red.redmine.ca", "https://black.redmine.ca/Pages/welcome.aspx", "http://webmail.redmine.ca", "https://blue.color.redmine.ca/groups"]
 => ["http://www.redmine.ca/", "http://red.redmine.ca", "https://black.redmine.ca/Pages/welcome.aspx", "http://webmail.redmine.ca", "https://blue.color.redmine.ca/groups"]
2.1.5 :002 > array.delete("https://blue.color.redmine.ca/groups")
 => "https://blue.color.redmine.ca/groups"
2.1.5 :003 > array
 => ["http://www.redmine.ca/", "http://red.redmine.ca", "https://black.redmine.ca/Pages/welcome.aspx", "http://webmail.redmine.ca"]
```

You must have a problem somewhere else.